# SQL server: Order by multiple columns incorrect syntax

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm using SQL server 2008.

```
SELECT resultTable.OrderNumber,
                resultTable.ProjectId,
                resultTable.BatchId,
                resultTable.CustomerId,
                resultTable.City,
                resultTable.Street,
                resultTable.PostalCode,
                resultTable.Country,
                resultTable.CreatedDate,
                resultTable.Name,
                COUNT(*) OVER() as OrdersCount,
                Row_Number() OVER 
                  (ORDER BY
                    CASE WHEN @sortBy = 'OrderNumber'
                    THEN resultTable.OrderNumber END,
                    CASE WHEN @sortBy = 'ProjectId'
                    THEN resultTable.ProjectId END,
                    CASE WHEN @sortBy = 'Address'
                    THEN resultTable.Country, resultTable.City, resultTable.Street, resultTable.PostalCode END,
                    CASE WHEN @sortBy = 'CreatedDate'
                    THEN resultTable.CreatedDate END) as RowIndex
FROM resultTable
```

This query fires with syntax error near ","

```
THEN resultTable.Country, resultTable.City, resultTable.Street, resultTable.PostalCode END,
```

If I remove the columns after the first "," everything is OK, but I'm trying to sort by address, which consists of 4 columns. Probably I cannot see something easy here.

PS: `@sortBy` is just a string parameter.

Comment: Case returns an expression. You cannot have `resultTable.Country, resultTable.City, resultTable.Street, resultTable.PostalCode` as result.

Comment: You might want to turn it around: `case when @sortBy = 'OrderNumber' then row_number() over (order by resultTable.OrderNumber) when ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
ORDER BY
   CASE WHEN @sortBy = 'OrderNumber'
     THEN resultTable.OrderNumber END,
   CASE WHEN @sortBy = 'ProjectId'
      THEN resultTable.ProjectId END,
   CASE WHEN @sortBy = 'Address'
     THEN resultTable.Country END,
   CASE WHEN @sortBy = 'Address' 
     THEN resultTable.City END, 
   CASE WHEN @sortBy = 'Address' 
     THEN resultTable.Street END, 
   CASE WHEN @sortBy = 'Address' 
     THEN resultTable.PostalCode END,
   CASE WHEN @sortBy = 'CreatedDate'
     THEN resultTable.CreatedDate END
```

Comment: wouldn't the first End - end the choosing and then I will end up sorting just by the first occurrence of `@sortBy = 'Address'`

Comment: @AntonBelev It would if this is a single `CASE` with bunch of `WHEN` parts, but here we have several `CASE` statements each working on it's own.

Comment: Yep, you are right : ) I liked a bit more your answer, than the podiluska's one. Also I'm choosing between two or more answers I'm giving priority to the one who has less rep.

Answer (score 3):

You probably want

```
 CASE WHEN @sortBy = 'Address'
      THEN 
         isnull(resultTable.Country,'') 
         + isnull( resultTable.City,'')
         + isnull( resultTable.Street,'')
         + isnull( resultTable.PostalCode,'') 
      end
```

Comment: It works but it will give incorrect sorting in cases when some parameter is null, longer/shorter and in general in unpredictable order (but only rarely )

Answer (score 0):

assuming @sortBy can only have those 4 values

```
CASE WHEN @sortBy = 'OrderNumber' THEN resultTable.OrderNumber END,
CASE WHEN @sortBy = 'ProjectId'   THEN resultTable.ProjectId END,
CASE WHEN @sortBy = 'CreatedDate' THEN resultTable.CreatedDate END,
CASE WHEN @sortBy = 'Address'     THEN resultTable.Country END,
resultTable.City, resultTable.Street, resultTable.PostalCode
```